# Finding text using array content for replacing

Tags: javascript

I am padding the beginning part of variables stored in an array

```
disp_var_name = []; //contains elements: a, b, g, c, f, salary, d, e;

fText = "(b>0&& ( salary > 33.00 ) )"

for(var pp=0; pp<disp_var_name.length; pp++){
   fText = fText.replace(disp_var_name[pp], "_sc_"+disp_var_name[pp]);
}
alert(fText);
```

The value of `fText` should be `(_sc_b>0&& ( _sc_salary > 33.00 ) )` but it displays `(_sc_b>0&& ( _sc_alary > 33.00 ) )`

What's wrong? How should i make it right?

I am working on a system like a c++ to js translator. I am padding it with `_sc_` so that variables in the sc(source code) is isolated from the system's variables.

Comment: `fText` is a boolean value when your for loop starts, you should be getting an error is your actual code different than what you have here?

Comment: You're initialising `fText` to a boolean value, so how does it make sense to use `.replace()` on it? Please show your actual array elements rather than listing them in a comment.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's this code for?

Comment: Are you sure about the current output? It looks to me like it would output `(_s_sc_c_b>0&& ( s_sc_alary > 33.00 ) )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop goes through the `disp_var_name` array in order, replacing the first occurrence of each of the specified strings. So the first thing it does is find "a" and replace it with "_sc_a", which gives you:

```
(b>0&& ( s_sc_alary > 33.00 ) )
```

Then it replaces the "b", which gives you:

```
(_sc_b>0&& ( s_sc_alary > 33.00 ) )
```

The it looks for a "g" but doesn't find one before moving on to replacing the first "c":

```
(_s_sc_c_b>0&& ( s_sc_alary > 33.00 ) )
```

There's no "f", "salary" isn't there anymore due to the previous replacement, and there's no "g", so the result would be:

```
(_s_sc_c_b>0&& ( s_sc_alary > 33.00 ) )
```

**If you use a regular expression that knows about word boundaries it will work:**

```
fText = fText.replace(new RegExp("\\b"+disp_var_name[pp]+"\\b", "g"), "_sc_"+disp_var_name[pp]);
```

That allows you to replace based on regex patterns `\ba\b`, `\bb\b`, etc. The double `\\` in the code I've shown is because `\` needs to be escaped if provided in a string.

Note that the `.replace()` only does a global replace if you pass it a regex with the `g` (global) flag set; if you pass it a string or a regex without the `g` it just replaces the first occurrence.